# HTML Table Scrollable with Columns

Tags: html, css

I am creating a table in html and it needs to be scrollable.  So I changed the display to block and made overflow-y scroll.  When I do this it makes the columns header not spaced out so there is a lot of excess space.  I know the display block setting is what causes this, but I need to make it scrollable.  how do I set this in css and html?

```
table {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 250px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: block;
}

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr class="rowTable header">
        <th class="cell">Date Submitted</th>
        <th class="cell">Bounty Name</th>
        <th class="cell">Company</th>
        <th class="cell">Paid</th>
        <th class="cell">Details</th>
        <th class="cell">Response</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for report in recentReports %}
      <tr class="rowTable">
        <td class="cell">{{report.date}}</td>
        <td class="cell"><a href="/_hunter/bounty/{{report.bountyID}}">{{report.name}}</td>
        <td class="cell"><a href="/_hunter/company/{{report.accountID}}">{{report.company}}</a></td>
        <td class="cell">{{report.amountPaid}}</td>
        <td class="cell">
          <button type="button" class="detailsButton" data-toggle="modal" 
          data-target="#detailsModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap" 
          data-ID={{report.reportID}}>
            View
          </button>
        </td>
        <td class="cell">
          <button type="button" class="messageButton" data-toggle="modal" 
            data-target="#messageModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap" 
            data-ID={{report.reportID}}>
            View
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr> 
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here is a photo of what happens.  I think its clear to see that what i want is the columns take take up the entire table evenly.  The image is of just the table, not the entire webpage.

[image]

Comment: Don't post images here, you are not helping yourself doing so. You need to post the relevant code which can be used to spot the problem. Where is the CSS. Are you using some framework?

Comment: Slim framework.  No other code to post.  Image was to illustrate problem.

Comment: Did you try setting a max-height property like so? http://jsfiddle.net/ftz99usk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the table in a DIV that has the settings your table has now (i.e. height and overflow), and let the table be a table...

Comment: Do you mean encase the table in another div?  i just tried this and it did not work.

Comment: @Danny Yes, a DIV with a fixed `heigth` and overflow-y: scroll` , and INSIDE THAT the table, where the table has `width: 100%` and more rows than fit into the DIV (and no fixed heigth or anything like that). 
I just tried it and it works.

Comment: I got it @Johannes you were right, i was messing something up

Answer (score 2):

You need to do what @Johannes suggests:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- put your table here-->
</div>
```

Change your Css to:

```
#wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 250px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: block;
}
table{
  width:100%
}
```

And you are done. If you find this answer useful, please up vote @Johannes answer. And if you feel Happy up vote mine to.

See example:

https://jsfiddle.net/ex239ck6/